# Serious error reporting on 18.04.3 LTS on start

Tags: apt, error-handling, patch

I have been working in total bliss for months now on my desktop until yesterday when the red warning flag appeared in the activities bar. Clicking on the button it  asks me to run package manager to see what is wrong, the error is:

```
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/la-mirrors.evowise.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-backports_InRelease (1),
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

If I try to show updates, nothing, install updates give same details as above with message:

'Failed to load the package list. this is a serious problem. Try later. If this appears again please report an error to developers.'

I hope that this is something that is easily put right, any help will be appreciated. I really don't want to lose information or use of my desktop. My apologies right away for being thick idiot, I'm not too well and this is not helping,(no it's not a hangover worst
 luck).

I have 7.8GiB Memory
AMD Athlon ii x 2 220processor x 2
NVD9
Gnome 3.28.2
OS 64-bit
DisK 983.4GB

I have taken a look to see if there is a problem with la-mirrors etc but no reports of anything wrong that I have found, I don't want to mess things up more than they already are.

system log file:

```
19:00:43 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4727 PROTO=2 
18:25:11 kernel: nouveau 0000:02:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
18:25:05 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4620 PROTO=2 
18:10:55 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577729455.516:791): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3139 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f50470b4f89 code=0x50000
18:10:46 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4577 PROTO=2 
18:08:21 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577729301.406:781): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/bob/Downloads/Tile-Adhesives-Norcros-Multi-Purpose-Primer-1LT~GPID_1100262007_TECH_0" pid=2881 comm="pool" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
18:08:21 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 338 callbacks suppressed
18:08:14 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577729294.538:433): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name=2F686F6D652F626F622F446F63756D656E74732F696D706F727465642066696C65732066726F6D2057696E2031302F52455720536F756E636172642043616C2E63616C pid=2881 comm="file-search" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
18:08:14 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 277 callbacks suppressed
18:08:09 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577729289.486:146): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name=2F686F6D652F626F622F446F63756D656E74732F696D706F727465642066696C65732066726F6D2057696E2031302F52455720536F756E636172642043616C2E63616C pid=2881 comm="file-search" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
18:08:09 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 14 callbacks suppressed
18:08:06 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4569 PROTO=2 
18:08:01 kernel: nf_conntrack: default automatic helper assignment has been turned off for security reasons and CT-based  firewall rule not found. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
18:08:00 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577729280.531:122): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name=2F686F6D652F626F622F446F63756D656E74732F696D706F727465642066696C65732066726F6D2057696E2031302F52455720536F756E636172642043616C2E63616C pid=2881 comm="pool" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
18:08:00 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 5 callbacks suppressed
18:07:46 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4568 PROTO=2 
18:06:19 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577729179.285:107): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=2297 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f795af46f89 code=0x50000
18:06:06 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4563 PROTO=2 
18:00:53 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577728853.344:97): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=2297 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f795af46f89 code=0x50000
18:00:46 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4547 PROTO=2 
18:00:01 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577728801.564:96): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=2297 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f795af46f89 code=0x50000
17:59:46 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4544 PROTO=2 
17:57:19 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577728639.906:95): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=2297 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f795af46f89 code=0x50000
17:57:16 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 23 callbacks suppressed
17:57:12 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1577728632.399:65): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=2297 comm="wineserver" exe="/snap/notepad-plus-plus/219/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/wineserver" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f795af46f89 code=0x50000
17:57:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4536 PROTO=2 
17:48:52 kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
17:48:47 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s7 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:10:be:f5:04:9e:a9:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=4511 PROTO=2 
17:48:09 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s7: link becomes ready
17:48:09 kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 enp0s7: MSI enabled
17:48:09 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s7: link is not ready
17:48:08 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577728087.879:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/freshclam" name="/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" pid=865 comm="freshclam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
17:48:02 kernel: input: HDA NVidia Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input14
17:48:02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577728075.915:53): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.vlc.vlc" pid=698 comm="apparmor_parser"
17:48:02 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 34 callbacks suppressed
17:48:02 kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
17:48:02 kernel: EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
 Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
 (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
17:48:02 kernel: MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
17:48:02 kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input9
17:48:02 kernel: kvm: disabled by bios
17:48:02 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
17:48:02 kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNEA] enabled at IRQ 18
17:48:02 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:05.0: Disabling MSI
17:48:02 kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LAZA] enabled at IRQ 22
17:48:02 kernel: [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 0
17:48:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
17:48:02 kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
17:48:02 kernel: fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
17:48:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:02:00.0: DRM: allocated 1600x900 fb: 0x60000, bo 0000000026df6346
17:48:02 kernel: [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
17:48:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:02:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00000200
17:48:02 kernel: [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
17:48:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB DDR3
17:48:02 kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
17:48:02 kernel: fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
17:48:02 kernel: checking generic (f9000000 130000) vs hw (f8000000 2000000)
17:48:02 kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNED] enabled at IRQ 19
17:48:02 kernel: shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
17:48:02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1577728070.255:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=463 comm="apparmor_parser"
17:48:02 kernel: ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
17:48:02 kernel: nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
17:48:02 kernel: ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
17:47:35 kernel: lp: driver loaded but no devices found
17:47:35 kernel: Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:2260988k FS
17:47:35 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
17:47:35 kernel: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
17:47:35 kernel: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
17:47:35 kernel: Listening on Syslog Socket.
17:47:35 kernel: Created slice System Slice.
17:47:35 kernel: Reached target Remote File Systems.
17:47:35 kernel: random: crng init done
17:47:35 kernel: Set hostname to <bob-G5200uk-m>.
17:47:35 kernel: Detected architecture x86-64.
17:47:35 kernel: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
17:47:35 kernel: random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
17:47:35 kernel: urandom_read: 6 callbacks suppressed
17:47:35 kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
17:47:35 kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
17:47:35 kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multi    Flash Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
17:47:35 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
17:47:35 kernel: random: wait-for-root: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
17:47:35 kernel: Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
17:47:35 kernel: xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (10843.000 MB/sec)
17:47:35 kernel:    generic_sse: 10421.000 MB/sec
17:47:35 kernel: xor: measuring software checksum speed
17:47:35 kernel: raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
17:47:35 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
17:47:35 kernel: scsi host4: usb-storage 1-8:1.0
17:47:35 kernel: usb-storage 1-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
17:47:35 kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
17:47:35 kernel: usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 058F63666471
17:47:35 kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
17:47:35 kernel: cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
17:47:35 kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
17:47:35 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
17:47:35 kernel:  sdb: sdb1
17:47:35 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       DVD-RAM GH60L    RD01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
17:47:35 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
17:47:35 kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST1000DM010-2EP1 CC43 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
17:47:35 kernel: ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
17:47:35 kernel: ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
17:47:35 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0461:0010.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [NOVATEK USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:02.0-4/input1
17:47:35 kernel: input: NOVATEK USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.1/0003:0461:0010.0003/input/input7
17:47:35 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0461:0010.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [NOVATEK USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:02.0-4/input0
17:47:35 kernel: input: NOVATEK USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/0003:0461:0010.0002/input/input6
```

I can also give the other log files if of any help?

Once again sincere thanks if anyone can help.

Also how do I report this to developers as requested?

Cheers

Comment: That file may have been corrupted. [My repos became corrupted: Unable to parse package file [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561276/my-repos-became-corrupted-unable-to-parse-package-file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks go to da_kingpin for pointing me in the right direction, and acknowledgement to IKE for the original answer back in the day.

"Try a sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* and then run sudo apt-get update again."

I was then able to use software updater and all's well!

Many thanks, can't tell you what a relief this is cheers.